# Road to Gehenna: What are the statue pieces for?

Tags: the-talos-principle

In the #1 hub in Road to Gehenna, I've found a number of statue pieces lying around.

I was wondering what these were for.  Is it possible to put the statue back together?

When I'm carrying pieces around, I don't seem to have the option to use the pieces on one another.

Edit: It seems you can put the statue together at the one-square pedestal near the warp point to the main hub.  However, completing the statue did nothing and the next time I reset a puzzle, the statue disappeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assembling the statue in Road to Gehenna has a much more subtle effect at first than assembling the statue in the main game. There is a very small pedestal located behind the entry portal to the area, where the statue can be assembled by using the pieces in order. Once the statue is complete, you will hear the sound of thunder, but nothing else will seem to happen. The actual effect of completing the statue only shows itself at the very end of the game, only once you've rescued every robot in the game.

> When you approach the area where the robots are waiting in the central hub once they have all been rescued, they will perform an Irish jig, accompanied by appropriate music.

This video shows the effects of reassembling the statue, starting at about 3:35. Earlier parts of the video show the locations of all the pieces of the statue.

This guide also shows the statue piece locations in a more static format: http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/179164-the-talos-principle-road-to-gehenna/faqs/72058?page=1#section55

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build the statue pieces back together. You need to find a base to use them. :-)

See this picture:
[image]

Some users at Steam [discussed](http://steamcommunity.com/app/257510/discussions/0/598199244889438168/) this for some time.

Comment: As the edit to my question (posted 3 hours before your response) pointed out, I found the base.  However, assembling the statue did nothing and the statue (and its pieces) vanished the next time I had to reset a puzzle, which I had to do when I got stuck trying to get one of the stars.  The pieces appear to be permanently gone now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the pedestal you're showing is from the main game. The question is in regards to the second statue, found in the Road to Gehenna DLC, which has different effects.